# curl specify multipart/form-data boundary in --form option

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

Is there any way to force a specific boundary in the multipart/form-data body when creating a curl request? The API that I am attempting to reach REQUIRES that the boundary is specified in the headers as "12345_boundary_54321". When generating a body using `--form` the boundary is set to a random boundary, but this gets rejected by the server when requesting.

```
curl --location --request POST $url \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/multipart/form-data; boundary=12345_boundary_54321' \
    --form 'filename="upload.zip"' \
    --form 'login="9873"' \
    --form 'token="abcde"' \
    --form 'name="uploadfile"' \
    --form '=@"upload.zip"'
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://curl.se/mail/lib-2007-09/0112.html

> libcurl doesn't really support this operation. If you're not happy with
> libcurl's multipart formpost as done built-in, you're better off:
>
> 1. using a normal POST and then handicraft the rest yourself in your
>    application.
>
> or
>
> 2. work on a patch that allows an application to alter the necessary pieces

Looks like nobody has opted for number 2, in the ~15 years since that post.